# How to make DEM that is non-contiguous?

Tags: qgis, dem, georeferencing, splitting

I am an amateur trying to produce a DEM that matches a map from the 1960s. I have succeeded in georeferencing the map and aligning it with a DEM, but I do not know how to make the DEM emulate the "cut out" portion of the map image. I call it the "cut out" portion because, being an amateur, I do not know the proper term.

Here is the relevant part of the map:

[image: Reference image]

The actual location of these islands is some ways south of the main island (Kyushu, Japan). Is there a best practice for making DEMs that handle such a non-contiguous scenario?  The only solution I can think of is to manually make the edits in Photoshop, but this feels too ham-fisted. I am using QGIS.

Comment: Inset maps should be treated as different datasets with their own extent, since they need not share origin, scale, projection, or even orientation with the main map canvas.

Comment: This is perfectly possible by using the map composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments to your question you should consider inset maps as different datasets (they have different scale in respect of the main map).
You should try:

1. add three (or more) layer, one for the main map and the other for the two (or more) inset maps.
2. georeference each layer separately according to the map portion and scale they are aimed to address.
3. Use map composer to reproduce the original map by adding three (or more) map to the layout (one for each previous georeferenced layer)

Useful link on how to use print composer to your needs: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html

Comment: So "inset map" is the term! Thank you very much.